# How to customize assertions in Cypress

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress

I need to test that an array of object contains a certain value. The test is written with Cypress, and for that, I use `cy.wrap` and `.some()`.

My code looks like this:

```js
const myCustomArray = [{ name: 'Lisa' }, { name: 'Katie' }];
cy.wrap(myCustomArray.some((user) => {
    if (user.name === 'Lisa') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })).should('eq', true);
```

This works well, but the problem is that it then returns me a very non-specific message in the Cypress console.

[image]

What I would like to have, is to change my code in a way that the message would be understandable. In the idea, it would be something like that:

```js
const myCustomArray = [{ name: 'Lisa' }, { name: 'Katie' }];
cy.wrap(myCustomArray.some((user) => {
    if (user.name === 'Lisa') {
      return 'user name is Lisa';
    }
  })).should('eq', 'user name is Lisa');
```

But this can't work as `.some()` can only return a boolean. I suppose there is an array function that could help me do that, but I can't find which one.

I am not sure whether:

- There are Cypress commands I am unaware of that could solve this issue, eg. customizing the assertion message.
- Or it can just be solved with using JavaScript

Both solutions would be fine for me.

Comment: Rather than putting the `if` inside the `some`, place it just after, using a ternary: `a.some() ? 'username is lisa' : null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `.find()` instead of `.some()`, and deep-eq the result,

```js
cy.wrap(myCustomArray.find(user => user.name === 'Lisa')) 
  .should('deep.eq', { name: 'Lisa' });
```

> ASSERT expected { name: Lisa } to deeply equal { name: Lisa }

or if you have big objects and just want to see the name,

```js
cy.wrap(myCustomArray.map(user => user.name).find(name => name === 'Lisa')) 
  .should('eq', 'Lisa');
```

> ASSERT expected Lisa to equal Lisa